# Returning object reference from C++ function

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

I have began learning C++ for Arduino and have run into some troubles.
I have some functions reading/writing to SPIFFS files.
Since the code for opening configuration files is common I would want to have a separate function to handle it.

I have come up with following function declaration

```
ConfigFileOpenStatus DeviceOpenConfigFile(const char *path, File *file);
```

The function accepts pointer to char array for the file path, and pointer to opened file.
I then tried to make following function definition

```
ConfigFileOpenStatus DeviceOpenConfigFile(const char *path, File *file)
{
    if (SPIFFS.exists(path))
    {
        file = &SPIFFS.open(path, "r+");
        return !file ? Failed : Opened;
    }
    else
    {
        file = &SPIFFS.open(path, "w+");
        return !file ? Failed : Created;
    }
}
```

That did not work as compiler complained with error **error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]**
As I understand this means that the file object will be disposed once DeviceOpenConfigFile function returns?

So my question is whether its possible to implement a function in a way where I can get File object reference and release it later?

Comment: What does `SPIFFS.open` return?

Comment: FS:File class object.

Comment: It's a horrible idea to use Arduino for learning C or microcontrollers. First of all, Arduino is C++, or some dialect of it. Second, all the "let me do the actual work" libraries won't let you actually learn anything. I'd recommend to use a bare metal MCU and write everything from scratch, even if that takes far more time.

Comment: completely agree with you @Lundin but for now I have to go that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `SPIFFS.open` apparently returns `File`, by value. The returned value will be a temporary variable available on that line. So taking the address of that one doesn't make any sense, for the same reason as `int func (void); ... &func()` doesn't make any sense. It has nothing to do with the surrounding `DeviceOpenConfigFile` function.
- It doesn't make sense to assign a new address to pointer passed by parameter, for the same reason as `void func (int x) { x = 0; }` doesn't make sense - you change a local variable only, nothing on the caller side gets changed and nothing gets returned to the caller.

It would seem that the solution you are looking for is this:

```
ConfigFileOpenStatus DeviceOpenConfigFile(const char *path, File* file)
{
  ...
  *file = SPIFFS.open(path, "r+");
```

where `file` is allocated on the caller-side.

Comment: that seem to do the job!

Comment: Or rather use `File& file`, since this is *C++* anyway.